# Divide N cake to M people with minimum wastes

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

So here is the question:

In a party there are n different-flavored cakes of volume V1, V2, V3 ... Vn each. Need to divide them into K people present in the party such that

- All members of party get equal volume of cake (say V, which is the solution we are looking for)
- Each member should get a cake of single flavour only (you cannot distribute parts of different flavored cakes to a member).
- Some volume of cake will be wasted after distribution, we want to minimize the waste; or, equivalently, we are after a maximum distribution policy

Given known condition that: if V is an optimal solution, then at least one cake, X, can be divided by V without any volume left, i.e., Vx mod V == 0

I am trying to look for a solution with best time complexity (brute force will do it, but I need a quicker way).

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

PS: It is not an assignment, it is an Interview question. Here is the pseducode for brute force:

```
int return_Max_volumn(List VolumnList)
{
    maxVolumn = 0;
    minimaxLeft = Integer.Max_value;
    for (Volumn v: VolumnList)
         for i = 1 to K people
             targeVolumn = v/i;
             NumberofpeoplecanGetcake = v1/targetVolumn + 
                 v2/targetVolumn + ... + vn/targetVolumn
             if (numberofPeopleCanGetcake >= k)
                  remainVolumn = (v1 mod targetVolumn) + (v2 mod targetVolumn)
                   + (v3 mod targetVolumn + ... + (vn mod targetVolumn)
                  if (remainVolumn < minimaxLeft)
                       update maxVolumn to be targetVolumn;
                       update minimaxLeft to be remainVolumn


     return maxVolumn
}
```

Comment: What have you considered?  Any code?

Comment: Have you tried anything? It looks like you just need somebody to do your assignment.

Comment: Have you tried to think how the "brute force" algorithm would be?

Comment: It's much more likely to be a programming contest problem than a homework. – someone well acquainted with both

Comment: "we want to minimize the waste" - How is waste calculated?  For example, if n > K, there will be at least n - K cakes that are not used at all.  Do they count as waste?  Or only the unused portions of cakes that have been cut?

Comment: It seems unfair that partygoers are only allowed one flavor. If it were my party I'd allow them to split up the cakes as they like such that they all get equal volumes total, but multiple flavors are allowed.

Comment: Sounds like a VRAM/Memory heap manager.  Can't divide your allocs across heaps - err cake flavors.  Minimize fragmentation, umm waste.  etc :)

Comment: @JAB: I think the person who came up with this question also wanted to minimize the number of people who actually visit the party.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So here is the algorithm I thought it would work:

1. Sort the volumes from largest to smallest.
2. Divide the largest cake to 1...k people, i.e., target = volume[0]/i, where i = 1,2,3,4,...,k
3. If target would lead to total number of pieces greater than k, decrease the number i and try again.
4. Find the first number **i** that will result in total number of pieces greater than or equal to K but **(i-1)** will lead to a total number of cakes less than k. Record this volume as baseVolume.
5. For each remaining cake, find the smallest fraction of remaining volume divide by number of people, i.e., division = (V_cake - (baseVolume*(Math.floor(V_cake/baseVolume)) ) / Math.floor(V_cake/baseVolume)
6. Add this amount to the baseVolume(baseVolume += division) and recalculate the total pieces all volumes could divide. If the new volume result in less pieces, return previous value, otherwise, repeat step 6.

Here are the java codes:

```
public static int getKonLagestCake(Integer[] sortedVolumesList, int k) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = k; i >= 1; i--) {
        double volumeDividedByLargestCake = (double) sortedVolumesList[0]
                / i;
        int totalNumber = totalNumberofCakeWithGivenVolumn(
                sortedVolumesList, volumeDividedByLargestCake);
        if (totalNumber < k) {
                result = i + 1;
                break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


public static int totalNumberofCakeWithGivenVolumn(
        Integer[] sortedVolumnsList, double givenVolumn) {
    int totalNumber = 0;
    for (int volume : sortedVolumnsList) {
        totalNumber += (int) (volume / givenVolumn);
    }
    return totalNumber;
}

public static double getMaxVolume(int[] volumesList, int k) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i : volumesList) {
        list.add(i);
    }

    Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Integer[] sortedVolumesList = new Integer[list.size()];
    list.toArray(sortedVolumesList);

    int previousValidK = getKonLagestCake(sortedVolumesList, k);
    double baseVolume = (double) sortedVolumesList[0] / (double) previousValidK;

    int totalNumberofCakeAvailable = totalNumberofCakeWithGivenVolumn(sortedVolumesList, baseVolume);

    if (totalNumberofCakeAvailable == k) {
        return baseVolume;
    } else {
        do
        {
            double minimumAmountAdded = minimumAmountAdded(sortedVolumesList, baseVolume);

            if(minimumAmountAdded == 0)
            {
                return baseVolume;
            }else
            {
                baseVolume += minimumAmountAdded;
                int newTotalNumber = totalNumberofCakeWithGivenVolumn(sortedVolumesList, baseVolume);

                if(newTotalNumber == k)
                {
                    return baseVolume;
                }else if (newTotalNumber < k)
                {
                    return (baseVolume - minimumAmountAdded);
                }else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }while(true);
    }

}

public static double minimumAmountAdded(Integer[] sortedVolumesList, double volume)
{
    double mimumAdded = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for(Integer i:sortedVolumesList)
    {
        int assignedPeople = (int)(i/volume);
        if (assignedPeople == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        double leftPiece = (double)i - assignedPeople*volume;

        if(leftPiece == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        double division = leftPiece / (double)assignedPeople;
        if (division < mimumAdded)
        {
            mimumAdded = division;
        }
    }

    if (mimumAdded == Double.MAX_VALUE)
    {
        return 0;
    }else
    {
        return mimumAdded;
    }
}
```

Any Comments would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

[This is a somewhat classic programming-contest problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3249).

The answer is simple: do a basic binary search on volume `V` (the final answer).

(Note the title says M people, yet the problem description says K. I'll be using `M`)

Given a volume `V` during the search, you iterate through all of the cakes, calculating how many people each cake can "feed" with single-flavor slices (`fed += floor(Vi/V)`). If you reach `M` (or 'K') people "fed" before you're out of cakes, this means you can obviously also feed `M` people with any volume < `V` with whole single-flavor slices, by simply consuming the same amount of (smaller) slices from each cake. If you run out of cakes before reaching `M` slices, it means you cannot feed the people with any volume > `V` either, as that would consume even more cake than what you've already failed with. This satisfies the condition for a binary search, which will lead you to the *highest volume **V** of single-flavor slices that can be given to M people*.

The complexity is `O(n * log((sum(Vi)/m)/eps) )`. Breakdown: the binary search takes log((sum(Vi)/m)/eps) iterations, considering the upper bound of `sum(Vi)/m` cake for each person (when all the cakes get consumed perfectly). At each iteration, you have to pass through at most all `N` cakes. `eps` is the precision of your search and should be set low enough, no higher than the minimum non-zero difference between the volume of two cakes, divided by `M*2`, so as to guarantee a correct answer. Usually you can just set it to an absolute precision such as `1e-6` or `1e-9`.

To speed things up for the average case, you should sort the cakes in decreasing order, such that when you are trying a large volume, you instantly discard all the trailing cakes with total volume < `V`  (e.g. you have one cake of volume `10^6` followed by a bunch of cakes of volume `1.0`. If you're testing a slice volume of `2.0`, as soon as you reach the first cake of volume `1.0` you can already return that this run failed to provide `M` slices)

### Edit:

The search is actually done with floating point numbers, e.g.:

```
double mid, lo = 0, hi = sum(Vi)/people;
while(hi - lo > eps){
    mid = (lo+hi)/2;
    if(works(mid)) lo = mid;
    else hi = mid;
}
final_V = lo;
```

By the end, **if you really need more precision than your chosen `eps`**, you can simply take an extra O(n) step:

```
// (this step is exclusively to retrieve an exact answer from the final
// answer above, if a precision of 'eps' is not acceptable)
foreach (cake_volume vi){
   int slices = round(vi/final_V);
   double difference = abs(vi-(final_V*slices));
   if(difference < best){
       best = difference;
       volume = vi;
       denominator = slices;
   }
}
// exact answer is volume/denominator
```

Comment: What do you mean a binary search on volume V? Which V you refer here? V is the target, and it does not need to be an interger

Comment: @KingSaber quoting you: "(say V, which is the solution we are looking for)". A binary search on the answer. So you're downvoting because you think binary searches only work on integers?

Comment: I believe the point here is: Ideally, total volume served is (V1 + V2 + ... Vn). So best case V is sum/k. We know worst case is Max(V1, V2, ..., Vn)/k. So binary search so see whether each candidate size is achievable; ie. can at least k whole slices of candidate size be sliced?

Comment: (Not the downvoter.) Yes, you can binary search rationals, but you'll get a range that converges in the limit rather than an exact answer, which would require a rounding procedure that Arthur so far has neglected to describe.

Comment: Jeez, okay, if the rounding really seems that hard, I'll include it in the answer.

Comment: I also don't see why the stated complexity should be accurate for the rounding variant.

Comment: @Arthur I downvote because your algorithm does not make sense. Give me your pseducode and I will vote you back.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat the rounding takes O(n).

Comment: @Arthur The running time should have a dependency on epsilon, and even the rounded result may not be correct (though it will be within epsilon of optimal).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat you're correct, the running time has a dependency on epsilon which was omitted for simplicity, as `eps` hadn't been explicitly mentioned yet, but I'll edit that. However, I disagree that the precision of the rounded result would be a problem, you can simply use an epsilon which is lower than half of the minimum non-zero difference of the volume of 2 cakes, divided by the amount of people, and the rounding procedure above would be guaranteed to give the exact answer.

Comment: @Arthur It is not correct. for example, in your code: double difference = abs(vi-(V*slices)); The difference should be all the remaining piece together, not just the remaining part of a single piece. Second, if you put {12,12,3} and K=7, your calculated answer is incorrect

Comment: @KingSaber the code you quoted is simply for retrieving **the exact answer out of the already correct floating-point answer `V`** as requested by David, it has nothing to do with the algorithm which calculates `V` and is explained above it. Hence the wording such as *"By the end,"* and *"you can simply take an extra step"*

Comment: @TimothyShields: I think the point here is that if the answer volume **V** is known, the greedy algorithm is optimal.  The trick is finding V.

Comment: @TimothyShields this algorithm provides **the optimal** solution, which is explained in the first paragraph, due to the properties of binary searches.

Comment: I wouldn't use an epsilon to terminate.  At each step where `V_curr < V_actual` (you feed everyone without running out of cake), increase V to `V_curr = min({V[i] / floor(V[i]/V)})`; this is a better lower bound since no individual cake gives you fewer slices.  And if for that adjusted `V_curr` no cake has a remainder of `V_curr` or greater, then `V_curr` is in fact the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach I would consider:

Let's assume that all of our cakes are sorted in the order of non-decreasing size, meaning that `Vn` is the largest cake and `V1` is the smallest cake.

1. Generate the first *intermediate solution* by dividing only the largest cake between all `k` people. I.e. `V = Vn / k`.
2. Immediately discard all cakes that are smaller than `V` - any intermediate solution that involves these cakes is guaranteed to be *worse* than our intermediate solution from step 1. Now we are left with cakes `Vb, ..., Vn`, where `b` is greater or equal to 1.
3. If all cakes got discarded except the biggest one, then we are done. `V` is the solution. END.
4. Since we have more than one cake left, let's improve our intermediate solution by redistributing some of the slices to the second biggest cake `Vn-1`, i.e. find the biggest value of `V` so that `floor(Vn / V) + floor(Vn-1 / V) = k`. This can be done by performing a binary search between the current value of `V` and the upper limit `(Vn + Vn-1) / k`, or by something more clever.
5. Again, just like we did on step 2, immediately discard all cakes that are smaller than `V` - any intermediate solution that involves these cakes is guaranteed to be *worse* than our intermediate solution from step 4.
6. If all cakes got discarded except the two biggest ones, then we are done. `V` is the solution. END.
7. Continue to involve the new "big" cakes in right-to-left direction, improve the intermediate solution, and continue to discard "small" cakes in left-to-right direction until all remaining cakes get used up.

P.S. The complexity of step 4 seems to be equivalent to the complexity of the entire problem, meaning that the above can be seen as an optimization approach, but not a real solution. Oh well, for what it is worth... :)

Comment: I don't think knowing the answer for the biggest two cakes helps much in finding the answer for the biggest three cakes.

Comment: @aschepler - It can help.  For example, if you get a solution V using cakes V[n]..V[i+1], and if V > V[i], then you know you have found the optimal solution.  But you're right, it might not help enough.

Comment: @aschepler: That's basically what I'm saying in my "P.S."

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach to a more efficient solution. Your brute force solution in essence generates an implicit of possible volumes, filters them by feasibility, and returns the largest. We can modify it slightly to materialize the list and sort it so that the first feasible solution found is the largest.

First task for you: find a way to produce the sorted list on demand. In other words, we should do O(n + m log n) work to generate the first m items.

Now, let's assume that the volumes appearing in the list are pairwise distinct. (We can remove this assumption later.) There's an interesting fact about how many people are served by the volume at position k. For example, with volumes 11, 13, 17 and 7 people, the list is 17, 13, 11, 17/2, 13/2, 17/3, 11/2, 13/3, 17/4, 11/3, 17/5, 13/4, 17/6, 11/4, 13/5, 17/7, 11/5, 13/6, 13/7, 11/6, 11/7.

Second task for you: simulate the brute force algorithm on this list. Exploit what you notice.